# Simile dilemma: Do leaves "fly like butterflies"?

Tags: literary-techniques, simile, as-like

> Leaves from the ground fly like butterflies .

What are the *leaves* being compared to?

1. flies
2. butterflies
3. ground
4. other leaves

Comment: 5. The 'flying' of leaves is what's being compared, to the true flying of butterflies. The full sentence is _Leaves from the ground fly like butterflies do._ In a secondary sense, as an aspect of the leaves' behaviour is being compared to that of butterflies, one could say loosely that the leaves are being compared to butterflies. But 'Leaves are like butterflies' on its own doesn't sound too wonderful. Unless you're after the comic 'Ogres are like onions' effect.

Comment: what are leaves being compared to?

Comment: Leaves have no nervous system, and hence their movements are not prompted by the processing of stimuli. They have no wings, whereas butterflies have four of them. They do not generate lift by flapping; their movement is passive, the result of being lifted and blown by air currents. They do not migrate with the seasons. Whoever decided to compare leaves to butterflies has thus shown themselves to be a singularly poor natural historian.

Comment: The leaves which have fallen to the ground are being lifted by the wind. The leaves appear to "flutter" **like** butterflies. Hence the leaves are compared to butterflies. This is a really easy question, I don't care whether leaves can physically fly or not, it's their **movements** in the wind which are being compared to that of those winged insects. You should visit ELL, [English Language for Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I changed the title because it had nothing to do with grammar, and perhaps the title is now a bit more interesting.

Comment: As for the many smart alec comments littering this page, it just confirms the supercilious pedantism that lies in the core EL&U. EL&U is dying, the number of visitors, questions posted and the quality of those very  questions is dropping faster than a meteorite in space.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I apologise in advance in the event that you consider this to be just another smart-alec comment, but the standard word is **pedantry,** not **pedantism.**  ;)

Comment: In this the author comparing like that ,its a multiple choice question. there they gave 4 choices fly,butterfly,ground,other leaves

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence:

> Leaves from the ground fly like butterflies.

Leaves are not compared to anything.

Comment: So you're saying that if you had read this sentence anywhere else, you would not have understood its meaning. You wouldn't have understood that the leaves *fluttering* from the ground were being compared to the fragile wings of a butterfly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm saying that the verbing of the noun is what is being compared, not the noun itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, "How should I answer this test question?", this site is not designed for that. But hopefully you have learned from the answers and comments here that it's not always a matter of "What is the right answer?"; sometimes it's "Was the question properly formed?"!

You now have a basis for arguing that "none of the above" is the correct answer. But this is essentially telling the teacher that this was a badly worded question. Chances are, he/she will not take kindly to having that pointed out.

Consider this a lesson: don't believe everything anyone tells you; not even your English teacher.